# can I use different buttons to call the same Action?

Tags: iphone

I am having different buttons witch should call the same action. Is there a way in IB to link more buttons to the same action?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just connect the buttons to File's owner and select the same action for each button.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an iphone programmer but i think you can solve this problem by creating a method which will call that action. And when you press each button you can even pass parameters through that method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, first create your function as IBAction in your code.
Then, create two button in IB, then go to the "Connection Inspector" panel and drag from "Touch Up inside" event to the File's Owner icon and select the function from the pop-up window. Repeat for both action.

If you implement your code as

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
```

you can use the parameter sender to recognize which button called the function

:)